# Get attribute of model through FK

Tags: django

Say I have these two models,

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Survey(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return "Survey for %s" % self.student.first_name
```

I want to list Survey objects by who they belong to. How do I access stuff in another model related by a foreign key dynamically?

This is the code that doesn't seem work (remember, student is the foreign key)...

```
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return "Survey for %s" % self.student.first_name
```

Comment: The code that you say doesn't work does actually work. If you think it doesn't, then you need to post the actual error message.

Comment: _slaps forehead_ I guess it was an unrelated issue then. Oops.

Comment: Remove the space between `__unicode__` and `(self)`